# MongoDb: How to use $unwind to unwind an array inside the object itself and not outside of it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have an aggregate function that returns this:

```
{"video": {
  "heart_users": [
      {
          "_id": "5f55465f19a7630017d6e3d5",
          "profile": "5f55465f19a7630017d6e3d6"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f89fd90fa8ca500170bff13",
          "profile": "5f89fd90fa8ca500170bff14"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f8bf4c0353ee400171ce239",
          "profile": "5f8bf4c0353ee400171ce23a"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f9002602c45b50017b4abe2",
          "profile": "5f9002602c45b50017b4abe3"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f95421d8b89f90017f9218b",
          "profile": "5f95421d8b89f90017f9218c"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5fda62586578d80017c9620f",
          "profile": "5fda62586578d80017c96210"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5ff310bcc1f74500178338d9",
          "profile": "5ff310bdc1f74500178338da"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5ff33cd00338aa0017d58f00",
          "profile": "5ff33cd10338aa0017d58f01"
      },
      {
          "_id": "60007322dfbcd30017d1a122",
          "profile": "60007322dfbcd30017d1a123"
      },
      {
          "_id": "6005994da1172516089d0446",
          "profile": "6005994ea1172516089d0447"
      },
      {
          "_id": "604e6637ff16e841a70751c1",
          "profile": "604e6638ff16e8d0c30751c2"
      }
  ]
 }
}
```

I would like to use `$unwind` and `$lookup` to populate `video.heart_users.profile` **AND** keep the same object structure above. In other words, I want the end-result to be something like this (Just like a normal `populate`).

```
{"video": {
  "heart_users": [
      {
          "_id": "5f55465f19a7630017d6e3d5",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f89fd90fa8ca500170bff13",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f8bf4c0353ee400171ce239",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f9002602c45b50017b4abe2",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5f95421d8b89f90017f9218b",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5fda62586578d80017c9620f",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5ff310bcc1f74500178338d9",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "5ff33cd00338aa0017d58f00",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "60007322dfbcd30017d1a122",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "6005994da1172516089d0446",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      },
      {
          "_id": "604e6637ff16e841a70751c1",
          "profile": {"profile_field":"profile_field_data"}
      }
  ]
 }
}
```

I have managed to achieve a close result by using `$unwind` externally:

```
 /** This works but, it unwinds heart_users externally instead of inside the heart_users array */
 {
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "video.heart_users",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "video.heart_users",
  },
},
{ $unwind: "$video.heart_users" },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "profiles",
    localField: "video.heart_users.profile",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "video.heart_users.profile",
  },
}
```

Any idea how to achieve the result I want?